# How to make a derived concrete class implicitly cast a generic base class?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base abstract generic class, which shoud give an ability to get the identifier of an object through an expression:

```
public abstract class Entity<TId> where TId : IEquatable<TId>
{
    protected abstract Expression<Func<Entity<TId>, TId>> GetEntityId();
}
```

But when I try to derive from it (and implement the abstract method):

```
public class IntEntity : Entity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    protected override Expression<Func<Entity<int>, int>> GetEntityId()
    {
        Expression<Func<IntEntity, int>> exp = e => e.Id;
        return exp; // CS0029 error
    }
}
```

I get CS0029 compile error, saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ConsoleApplication1.IntEntity,int>>`'
>   to
>   '`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ConsoleApplication1.Entity<int>,int>>`'

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is inherently unsafe.

Had that been legal, you would be able to pass a different class inheriting `Entity<int>` to your function that can only accept `IntEntity`s.

Instead, you can use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
public abstract class Entity<TEntity, TId> 
    where TId : IEquatable<TId> 
    where TEntity : Entity<TEntity, TId>
{
    protected abstract Expression<Func<TEntity, TId>> GetEntityId();
}
```

Comment: +1: That's just, what I needed....only the last `where` should be `where TEntity : Entity<TEntity, TId>`, I guess